# IE6 Click on binding event before document.ready destroys the binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, internet-explorer-6

Hey, So this is a rather weird issue, so what we have is a site that the javascript is at the bottom of the page. The html loads first and then we `$(document).ready()` element events. The issue I have right now is in IE6 (Stupid I know) where if you click on the item that is about to or during the loading of the page, will destroy the binding event. If you wait for the page to fully load then it runs the page correctly.

What I thought of so far:
 *Create an overlay on the page and then on document.ready remove it so that the click events aren't becoming broken.*

Your probably thinking why don't you just push the JS files into the header? Well tuff-noogies can't do that either. (That might help)

Let me know what you think.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

$(document).ready() is only executed after the page is loaded. So during the page load, $(document).ready() is still not called and events are still not bound.

The solution is to bind the events as soon as elements appear on the page. It's a bit ugly, but for slow connections, it might be the only way.